# Delete certain columns and add horizontally in AW. So many columns that I cannot type each one

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk

I have been struggling more than a day and I cannot make my script work. Please help.

My txt file extends to 500 columns.

I need to delete columns 5,9,13,21,..., always delete n=4 column.

Then, after removing the columns I mentioned above, I need to add all the columns remaining, BUT NOT taking into account ONLY the column 1.
For this I am using:

`awk '{print $1,$2+$3+.........}' >> comb.xvg`

The thing is that don't want to go manually adding until I reach 500.

My final document should have only two columns.

- The first from the very beginning
- And the another column that has the sum of all the other ones (please be aware that I am adding horizontally and not vertically). 
  The sum is done horizontally from column 2 to the column 500.

Could someone please help me to do this? I have tried different sets using for loop but they fail.

I am new at this and also using stack. Please my apologies if I am not fully clear but I cannot upload pics.

Thanks.

Comment: Please convert the files to text

Comment: to get verifiable solutions please create a sample data input and expected output.  Since the same formula will apply all the rows, the length of the sample is not important.

Comment: Oh man. This needs an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

this script will sum up the columns 2,3,4, 6,7,8, 10,.. (that is skipping 5,9,...4k+1...)

```
awk '{sum=0; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) sum+=(i-1)%4?$i:0; print $1,sum}'
```

**Explanation**
We're summing up the elements in the row.  If we were to add them all, `sum+=$i` would do, however you want to skip the values at indices `2k+1`, so we use the ternary operator v=c?a:b, that is `if(c) v=a; else v=b`.  `(i-1)%4` is the modulus by 4, will be zero for i=5,9,...,2k+1.

deleting the columns doesn't seem to be necessary since you're not printing the resulting panel.

to test

```
$ seq 20 | xargs -n 10 | awk ...
```

prints

```
1 40
11 110
```

to verify: sum(2+3+...+10) = 54, so after removing 5 and 9, you'll get 40. For sum(12+13+...+20) it's 10 more for each element, i.e. 40+7*10=110.

Follow up question:  How to add s2=2,6,10...; s3=3,7,11...; s4=4,8,12...

```
awk '{s2=s3=s4=0; 
      for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=4) 
        {s2+=$i; s3+=$(i+1); s4+=$(i+2)}; 
      print $1, s2, s3, s4}'
```

Comment: Thanks it worked awesome.
I just have a question: Could you please briefly explain the symbols inside the sum?
As a further analysis I need to add columns 2,6,10,....; then columns 3,7,11,15,.....; finally columns 4,8,12,16,......

The first column is time, second to fourth are x-y-z trajectories. This just repeats until 500 columns. Therefore, I need to analyze each trajectory as well.